# JS works with .include but fails with .extend

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13

I made this JS to add a functionality on a form (backend) that computes a field when the event click is triggered. So far the code recomputes when I use ".include" but the whole JS in all views fail since I'm using ".include". When I try to use extend my code does nothing. Looks like Odoo doesn't add the extended code to the JS engine so my question is, what am I doing wrong here? Is there something else I need to add so my code works as extended?

```
odoo.define('med_care.TestRenderer', function (require) {
"use strict";

var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
var FormRenderer = require('web.FormRenderer');
var FormView = require('web.FormView');

var TestFormRenderer = FormRenderer.extend({
    events: _.extend({}, FormRenderer.prototype.events, {
        'click .sign_selector': '_onSignSelectorClicked',
    }),
    init: function (parent, state, params) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.fields = state.fields;
        this._onSignSelectorClicked = _.debounce(this._onSignSelectorClicked, 300, true);
    },
    confirmChange: function (state, id, fields, e) {
        var self = this;
        if (state.model == 'med.test') {
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments).then(function () {
                self.canBeSaved(self.state.id);
            });
        }
    },
    _onSignSelectorClicked: function (event) {
       this.state.data.telephone = '333';
       if (this.state.model == 'med.test') {
           var info_test = {
               dataPointID: this.state.id,
               changes: {telephone: '333'},
               viewType: "form",
               notifyChange: true
           };
           var odoo_event = this.trigger_up('field_changed', info_test);
           this.confirmChange(this.state, this.state.id, "telephone",          
           odoo_event)
        }
    },
});
var TestFormView = FormView.extend({
    config: _.extend({}, FormView.prototype.config, {
        Renderer: TestFormRenderer,
    }),
});
viewRegistry.add('test_form', TestFormView);
return TestFormView;
});
```

Comment: Extends create a new Class that inherit the functionality of the given class, you added a new view type of you form, I think you need to create the form view using the tag `<test_form>` not `<form>` if you want this to work on that view, but also you can check witch model is loaded to apply this behavior. you can find a lot of example on how to check the current model in stackoverflow answers. I hope i'm right ^^

Comment: Hey! I already discover how. I haven't tested your solution since I found another. All I needed to do to extend the form renderer was to return TestFormRenderer and on create extension for FormView. In the <form js_class="test_formview"> (XML) I just add the name of the extended form view added in the registry (FormView).